# More than one zone doesn't work in K6 and load impact

Tags: k6

I'm making load tests of my web page. I'm using K6 and load impact to do that. I have a problem because when I'm triggering load JS script from my PC there is only one ZONE, if same test will be run from LadImpact app it is fine, two zones were used. Maybe someone have same problem. I asked LI support but it takes quite long to get answer.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow, if your question does not attract answers, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get good tips on how to get improve it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This has been identified as a bug in the latest k6 release, v0.23.0, affecting the `k6 cloud ...` command (but doesn't affect tests run through the Load Impact web app as `k6 run ...` is being used for those tests). A bugfix release will be issued in the next few days. To workaround the problem you can temporarily downgrade to k6 [v0.22.1](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases/tag/v0.22.1).

Comment: Fixed in the v0.23.1 release:  https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases/tag/v0.23.1

Answer (score 1):

The [v0.23.1](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases/tag/v0.23.1) k6 release fixes the bug affecting load zones.